# DBIOAction cleanUp or asTry do not lead to internal execution

Tags: scala, slick

I'm trying to test whether side effects get executed or not. Neither

```scala
DBIOAction.successful(()).cleanUp(_.fold {
  println("yeay!")
  DBIOAction.successful(())
} { _ => 
  println("aww.")
  DBIOAction.successful(())
})
```

nor

```scala
DBIOAction.successful(()).asTry.map {
  case Succeed(_) => println("yeay!")
  case Failure(_) => println("aww.")
}
```

print anything. I am not too familiar w/ Slick but it may need to place `run` somewhere. Is there a way to provide a lightweight runtime for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consulting [the documentation of I/O actions](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/concepts.html#database-io-actions):

> Operations that can be executed on a database are called *database I/O
> actions* (`DBIOAction`). Several operations on queries and tables create
> I/O actions, for example `myQuery.result`, `myQuery.result.headOption`,
> `myQuery += data` or `myTable.schema.create`. Actions can be composed with
> combinators like `andThen`, `flatMap`, `DBIO.seq` or `transactionally`.
>
> Just like a query, an I/O action is only a *description* of an operation.
> Creating or composing actions does not execute anything on a database.
> Combined actions always consist of *strictly linear* sequences of other
> actions. Parts of an action never run concurrently.

and [about results](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.3.3/concepts.html#results):

> Any *action* can be run on a database to obtain the results (or perform
> side effects such as updating the database). Execution is always
> asynchronous, i.e. it does not block the caller thread. Any kind of
> action can be run to obtain a `Future` that is eventually completed with
> a result when the execution is finished (`myDatabase.run(myAction)`).
> Actions that produce a sequence of values usually support streaming
> results as well. Such an action can be combined with a database to
> produce a Reactive Streams `Publisher` (`myDatabase.stream(myAction)`).
> The action is executed when a consumer subscribes to the Publisher.

you have to `database.run(ioAction)` to have any side effect (including `println`) evaluated.

Comment: thank you! This is in a unit test. Is there a way to provide a lightweight runtime for testing purposes?

Comment: Tests with database are by definition integrations tests. Use some test containers with your DB of choice and connect to them in test (I strongly suggest NOT to use H2 in tests when you have Postgres on prod) OR hide whatever code runs DB queries behind an interface that returns `Future`s instead of `DBIOAction`s and have your unit tests talk to a mock returning `Future`s.